# Scrapy timeout after a while

Tags: python, scrapy, timeout, web-crawler

I work on crawling the text from https://www.dailynews.co.th, and here is my question.

My spider worked almost perfect at first, crawled about 4000 pages.

```
2018-09-28 20:05:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 4161 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

And then it started to raise tons of TimeoutErrors from almost all urls, like this.

```
2018-09-28 20:06:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.dailynews.co.th/tags/When%20Will%20You%20Marry>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/app/.local/share/virtualenvs/monolingual-6kEg5ui2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-18.7.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1416, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
File "/usr/local/app/.local/share/virtualenvs/monolingual-6kEg5ui2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-18.7.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/failure.py", line 491, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
File "/usr/local/app/.local/share/virtualenvs/monolingual-6kEg5ui2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
File "/usr/local/app/.local/share/virtualenvs/monolingual-6kEg5ui2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-18.7.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/local/app/.local/share/virtualenvs/monolingual-6kEg5ui2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 351, in _cb_timeout
raise TimeoutError("Getting %s took longer than %s seconds." % (url, timeout))
TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.dailynews.co.th/tags/When%20Will%20You%20Marry took longer than 5.0 seconds..
```

This was my second try and I decreased CONCURRENT_REQUESTS from 32 to 16, AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY from 32.0 to 4.0, and DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT from 15 to 5. The problem was not solved but I got more pages than the first try (from 1000 to 4000).

I also tried `scrapy shell` on the failed urls (while my spider was still running), I got a response with 200 which means the connection is fine itself.

I wonder if I got banned or something else, can anybody give me a clue on this? Thanks a lot.

FYI, here is my settings file.

```
# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'protocol.middlewares.RotateUserAgentMiddleware': 110,
'protocol.middlewares.MaximumAbsoluteDepthFilterMiddleware': 80,
'protocol.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 543
}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 0.1
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 10
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 4.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 5
DEPTH_LIMIT = 100
DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
```

And here is my spider code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from parse_config import parse_config


class ProtocolSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'protocol'
    start_urls = ['https://www.dailynews.co.th,']
    custom_settings = {
        'JOBDIR': 'crawl_job'
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProtocolSpider, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.arg_dict = parse_config(kwargs)
        self.start_urls = self.arg_dict['start_urls']
        # print self.start_urls
        self.allowed_domains = self.arg_dict['allowed_domains']
        self.output_file = open(self.arg_dict['output_file'], 'ab')
        self.rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=self.arg_dict['allow_url'], deny=self.arg_dict['deny_url']),
                 callback="parse_all", follow=True),
        )
        self._compile_rules()
        self.use_web_proxy = self.arg_dict['use_web_proxy']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.parse_all(response)
        return super(ProtocolSpider, self).parse(response)

    def parse_all(self, response):
        self._record_url(response)
        self._extract_all_p(response)
        self._extract_all_div(response)

    def _record_url(self, response):
        self.output_file.write('url_marker: %s' % response.url + '\n')

    def _extract_all_p(self, response):
        if self.arg_dict['extract_all_p']:
            p_ls = response.xpath('//p/text()').extract()
            p_string = '\n'.join([p.strip().encode('utf8') for p in p_ls if p.strip()])
            self.output_file.write(p_string + '\n')

    def _extract_all_div(self, response):
        if self.arg_dict['extract_all_div']:
            div_ls = response.xpath('//div/text()').extract()
            div_string = '\n'.join([div.strip().encode('utf8') for div in div_ls if div.strip()])
            self.output_file.write(div_string + '\n')

    def close(self, spider, reason):
        self.output_file.close()
        return super(ProtocolSpider, self).close(spider, reason)
```

Comment: Well, if i were the admin of that site and saw things like: 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS from 32 to 16' i'd ban you, permanently. You could try to go through proxies tho ... but really savvy web masters will detect even automated requests every few seconds and ban without question or second chances.(i'm speaking from experience here)

Comment: @meissner_ thanks for your advice. But as we can see I have set the concurrency to each server to 4, and enabled the autothrottle, the real request rate was far more lower than the theoretical one. In fact I only got about 10 pages per min, I believe that is quite "gentle" for a website crawler. By the way, I don't think this problem is caused by being banned since I could still access the timeout url by `scrapy shell`.

Comment: Indeed, 10 per min seems to be a pretty benign rate and since it's working from the shell a banning seems unlikely... on the other hand: you never know.